# How do I get a reference to a Class<T> for generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I'm using a library that has a method like this:

```
public class LibClass<T> {
  public LibClass(Class<T> arg1) {...}
}
```

Now I want to create an instance of `LibClass` for `List<String>`

```
LibClass<List<String>> instance = new LibClass<List<String>>(/* what goes here? */);
```

How can I create a Class object that will satisfy the argument when that class uses generics?

Comment: what do you use the class for?

Comment: Note that whatever you get will just pretend to be a `Class<List<String>>`.  It'll actually just be `List.class`, and it won't actually know it's a `List<String>`.

Comment: Here a dirty hack : `LibClass<List<String>> instance = new LibClass<List<String>>((Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class);` following @LouisWasserman comment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's fine, it's for compile-time checking anyway.